# How can I disable the href display in the lower left corner of browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink

Is there a way to disable the 'tooltip' (that may not be the correct technical term) which displays the href in the lower left corner of the screen when a user hovers over a particular link?

ie.

```
 <a id="contactme2" href="#"></a>
```

The href is "#" so the visitor sees a '#' in the lower left corner which confuses some visitors. I'd like to be able to disable that entirely as needed.

NB: I am -not- talking about the Title attribute.

Comment: If a link doesn't go somewhere, don't use a link. And no, you can't hide or disable that, its not a DOM object, it's part of the browser functionality.

Comment: In this case instead of using 'a' tag you can use some other tags like <button>, <input> or even <div>. If you want something to happen without reloading the page you can still do it using Javascript and Jquery

Comment: I fail to see why this was down voted. I understand that it's not best practice for new systems. But often, we have to work with older systems that use just this sort of thing. One shouldn't be down voted for asking if something is simply -possible-.

Answer (score 1):

You can use other html tags, instead using a tag

```
<span onClick="callme()">Text</span>
```

also on span use `style="cursor: hand;"` to show cursor when someone mouse hovers.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure why you would want to do this, but I would recommend using a tag other than the `<a>` tag since this tag is what supplys the browser with the link location.

By using the `<span>` or `<button>` tags you can replicate the same link functionality without supplying the browser with an actual link for it to preview while hovered.

`<span onClick="dosomething()">Contact Me</span>`

Then, your `dosomething` function might look like this:

```
function dosomething(){
window.location = "#";
//or whatever code you want to run
}
```

In short, you could also do this

`<span onClick="window.location='#'">Contact Me</span>`

For some better link decoration you could also add this to your CSS:

```
.txt {
    text-color: blue;
}
.txt:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

and add `class="txt"` to your `<span>`